# If the checkbox is checked, send a message to the backend

Tags: php, magento

I edited inline.phtml in order to show a checkbox option to let visitors choose if they want a gift packaging or not.

```
<?php case 'onepage_checkout': ?>
<div class="gift-messages">
    <h3><?php echo $this->__('Do you have any gift items in your order?'); ?></h3>
    <p class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allow_gift_messages" id="allow_gift_messages" value="1"  class="checkbox" />
        <label for="allow_gift_messages"><?php echo $this->__('Add gift options.') ?></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is working.

But **when the checkbox is checked, I would like to update the history of the order in the backend by a comment ('With a gift packaging').**

Should I use the addstatushistorycomment() function here?

Comment: you can use onchange event of jquery for getting checkbox checked status and than use ajax for udpate history.

Comment: thanks for your advice, a javascript code solved the issue. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to do it was to edit the javascript in the inline.phtml page.

When the checkbox is checked, a message 'With a gift packaging' is added in the textearea of the field 'gift-message-whole-message'.
When the checkbox is not checked, no message appears in the textarea.
Also, the div containing the textarea ('allow-gift-messages-for-order-container') is hidden by CSS (display:none) in order not to be seen by user.

For information, the javascript edited in inline.phtml:

```
if(!window.toogleVisibilityOnObjects) {
var toogleVisibilityOnObjects = function(source, objects) {
var message = document.getElementById('gift-message-whole-message');
    if($(source) && $(source).checked) {
    message.value = "With a gift packaging"
        objects.each(function(item){
            $(item).show();
            $$('#' + item + ' .input-text').each(function(item) {
                item.removeClassName('validation-passed');
            });
        });
    } else {
    message.value = "";
        objects.each(function(item){
            if ($(item)) {
                $(item).hide();
                $$('#' + item + ' .input-text').each(function(sitem) {
                    sitem.addClassName('validation-passed');
                });
                $$('#' + item + ' .giftmessage-area').each(function(sitem) {
                    sitem.value = '';
                });
                $$('#' + item + ' .checkbox').each(function(sitem) {
                    sitem.checked = false;
                });
                $$('#' + item + ' .select').each(function(sitem) {
                    sitem.value = '';
                });
                $$('#' + item + ' .price-box').each(function(sitem) {
                    sitem.addClassName('no-display');
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}